# PHP Code optimization on Data Nesting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image]

Above is the sample table that I am building which is based on `Codeigniter`. I already have finished it however the performance is a major turn off. The page loads around 17-19 seconds which is a 
definite no go for me.

The total rows of the table is 189 and the total columns is 98.

What I did is is the following:

**CONTROLLER**

```
 function test() {

            $data['departments'] = $this->test_model->get_All_Department(); //All Departments
            $data['sub_dept_uncat'] = $this->test_model->get_Sub_Department(0, 0); //All Sub Dept without parent 
            $data['object_categories'] = $this->test_model->get_All_Object_Category(); //all object categories

}
```

My controller is simple, because I loaded the other models directly to the view *(which is definitely not advisable // The least thing I can do as of now)*

**VIEW**

As for the table headers, what I did was:

```
        <tr>
        <?php
//Departments
            if($departments):
                foreach($departments as $department):
                    $dep_num++; //Department counter increment. // also used in colspan
                    echo '<th colspan="'.$this->lbpform2_model->count_Sub_Department($department['id']).'">'.$department['title'].'</th>';
                    echo '<th rowspan="2">TOTAL '.$department['title'].'</th>';
                endforeach; //$departments
            endif; //$departments
        ?>


//Uncategorized Departments

    if($sub_dept_uncat) {
            foreach($sub_dept_uncat as $dept_uncat) {

                    $uncat_dep_num++; //Uncategorized Sub Department Header Increment. // also used in colspan
                    echo '<th rowspan="2">'.$dept_uncat['title'].'</th>';

                } //$sub_dept_uncat
            } //$sub_dept_uncat
        </tr>
```

Same theory goes with the table body.
I loop the Object Categories. Inside, I loop the Sub categories, and the objects. And again, I loop the departments in order to get the rows.

When getting the value, I simply load this on the view:

```
<?=$this->test_model->get_object_data($object_id, $subdep_id)?>
```

**Experience**

What I experience is the page loads very slow and I definitely need an optimization. I cannot think of any idea on how to optimize it, that displays the exact result of what I have already coded.

Comment: Have you tried using the [profiler](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) if your queries are slow? `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` You can also use the [benchmarking class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html) to diagnose code performance

Comment: post your models where your queries are and if its possible your db structure too